# Outlook addin for web is working on web but not on Office Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2013

[image: Outlook Version]

It is working on the web but not on the desktop. I have read all the available threads already but I am still not able to figure out the reason

Please guide, any help would be appreciated

My Manifest is compatible with outlook 2013 or later, what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors?

The [Troubleshoot user errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/testing-and-troubleshooting) page describes the information to help resolve common issues that your users or you encounter with an Office Add-in.

You can also use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to identify and debug issues with your add-ins.

Comment: Did you try to use Fiddler?

Comment: Yes, I did it is not even calling localhost:3000

Comment: I even tried to install some other plugins available on store, like yelp even those doesn't appear ,is my version support outlook addin?